# CountIfs horribly slow in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario:**

I have a scenario where each account can have many customers, and each customer can have many accounts (many to many).

I am creating a report to count how many accounts each customer has.

[image]

To do this, I am using this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(CustAccount[Customer ID], [@[Customer ID]])
```

This works fine. The problem is that the CustAccount table contains 65K rows. The report table contains 45K Customer IDs. It is taking more than 20 minutes to perform this calculation on a relatively slow PC.

I am using the obvious optimizations such as:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Is it looping all of the 65K rows each time to acquire a count for every row in the 45K table?
Any ideas on what can be done to significantly improve performance?

Comment: A pivot table will nicely present the count of the number of accounts a customer has, without having to manually maintain a list of all accounts as the source for your lookup.

Comment: Any other options? Due to bureaucracy I must stick to VBA...

Comment: If you must use VBA it would be useful to show the rest of your existing code. Possible approaches include running a SQL query against your CustAccount data to summarise count by Customer, or creating a Dictionary object to summarize the counts.

Comment: Running a SQL query on an excel table? How is that possible? Besides, the only other VBA code involved in this case is the one that populates the table. I meant that I must stick to "VBA and excel formulas", correcting myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you can run a SQL query on data in Excel:

```
Sub SQLTester()
'Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX data objects"
'Workbook must have been saved to run this

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    wb.Save

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & _
               ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"

    oRS.Open " select Customer, count(Account) " & _
             " from [Data test$A1:B2201] group by Customer", oConn

    wb.Sheets("Data test").Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset oRS

    oRS.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to accumulate the count of accounts by CustomerID in a Dictionary object, then write out the dictionary and sort it by CustomerID.  See example below:

```
Sub CountAccountsByCustomerID()
    ' Need to add reference in Menu > Tools > References
    ' turn checkbox on for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to use dictionary
    Dim customers As Dictionary
    Set customers = New Dictionary
    Dim AccountTable As Range
    Set AccountTable = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Dim offset As Long
    offset = 0
    Dim OutputTable As Range
    Set OutputTable = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2")
    Dim customer As String
    Dim item As Variant

    ' Build dictionary of counts of accounts for all CustomerIDs
    Do While AccountTable.offset(offset, 0) <> ""
        customer = AccountTable.offset(offset, 1).Value
        If customers.Exists(customer) Then
            customers(customer) = customers(customer) + 1
        Else
            customers(customer) = 1
        End If
        offset = offset + 1
    Loop

    'Write table of customerIDs and counts of accounts
    offset = 0
    For Each item In customers.Keys
        OutputTable.offset(offset, 0).Value = Str(item)
        OutputTable.offset(offset, 1).Value = customers.item(item)
        offset = offset + 1
    Next

    'Sort OutputTable by CustomerID (assumes column headings in row above range OutputTable
    OutputTable.CurrentRegion.Sort OutputTable, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes

End Sub
```